# Why is the "Present continuous" used?

Tags: grammar, verb-forms

I've read the [BBC English grammar challenge](http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammarchallenge/pdfs/14_perfectpassives_expert.pdf) and faced with the following sentence:

> But don't forget, when ***people are speaking***, they often shorten words
>   like is or has, so they sound like this: [...]

I don't understand why we use Present Continuous tense instead of Present Simple tense? I think that people ***speak*** in general point, but not in the current moment. Where is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: Present tense (_when people speak_) would be just as acceptable.

Comment: @200_success Whether a present simple tense distorts a point of the sentence?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: No, the meaning remains the same. The difference is very minor and subtle. Simple present: "when people speak" = "on those occasions when they speak", versus "when people are speaking" = "during the action of speaking". This nuance makes no difference to what is conveyed *in this context*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When** is a relative adverb in this sentence. we can use "when" to say something happens at the same time when we are **doing** something else.

> But don't forget, when people are speaking, they often shorten words like is or has.

Definition :

> **2.b.** When doing something: *She was often nervous when facing the camera.*
>
> <sub>[Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/when)</sub>

To me **present progressive form** fits better in this sentence because it implies **speaking duration** a bit better than the **simple present form.**

Comment: I do not think you are answering the OP's question here. OP is specifically asking about the difference - if any - between present simple and "present continuous" in a particular context.